# Element UI DatePicker (vue2)

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I've a problem when I use DatePicker from Element UI I don't have buttons and placeholder is empty.
Does anyone has same problem with me?

The first pick is mine datepicker, the second is default
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7rDQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twkNH.png)

I were tried to find something about it at element ui docs, google but still got nothing.
Also I checked element node modules and everything looks like Ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Fixed it, by adding new library with date-time-picker